# All linear combinations diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ implies commuting.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{C}, xA+yB$ is diagonalizable.
>
> Show that $AB=BA$.

My idea (not really an attempt) :

It suffices to show that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneous diagonalizable. Then one can use the theorem that says $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable at the same time if and only if they commute.

Does anyone has a way to prove that  $A$ and $B$ are simultaneous diagonalizable ?

Comment: This was asked on mathoverflow [here.][1]


  [1]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164209/diagonalization-for-sums-of-hermitian-matrices

Comment: [It](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.4420.pdf) is a paper that studied the more general case.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. This can't work because I didn't really make use of the assumption that $A+uB$ is diagonalizable (in a sense, I did, but I could run almost the same argument by just looking at one eigenvector/eigenvalue).

Comment: In view of George's comment, it's very unlikely that this is an exercise. Where does this question come from?

Comment: @user1551 At usual, its an ENS oral, but this one in particularly infamous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Definition:** A pair $ (A,B) $ of complex $ (n \times n) $-matrices is said to have **Property L** if there exist orderings $ (\lambda_{i})_{i = 1}^{n} $ and $ (\mu_{i})_{i = 1}^{n} $ respectively of the eigenvalues of $ A $ and $ B $ such that
>   $$
> \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^{2}: \quad
> \operatorname{Spectrum}(x A + y B) = \{ x \lambda_{i} + y \mu_{i} \}_{i = 1}^{n}.
> $$

By Theorems 3 and 4 of [T.S. Motzkin, O. Taussky, *Pairs of Matrices with Property L. II*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **80** (1955) 387-401](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-080-02/S0002-9947-1955-0086781-5/S0002-9947-1955-0086781-5.pdf), if $ \lambda A + \mu B $ is a pencil in which all matrices are diagonalizable, then $ (A,B) $ has Property L, and moreover, $ A $ and $ B $ commute.

---

**EDIT:**

Using some concepts in algebraic geometry, Motzkin and Taussky showed that the result above holds for any field $ \mathbb{K} $ (if $ \mathbb{K} $ has finite characteristic, then they further assumed that $ \operatorname{char}(\mathbb{K}) \geq n $). Using complex analysis, Kato (in his book *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators*, pp. 82-85) gave another proof that is valid only for $ \mathbb{C} $. Using Kato’s method, Friedland (in [*A Generalization of the Motzkin-Taussky Theorem*, Linear Algebra Appl. **36** (1981) 103-109](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379581902238)) and De Seguins Pazzis (in [*On Commuting Matrices and Exponentials*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **141 (3)** (2013) 763-774](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2013-141-03/S0002-9939-2012-11396-6/S0002-9939-2012-11396-6.pdf) - An easier access is on arXiv -) showed generalizations of the previous result that are valid only for $ \mathbb{C} $.

Comment: In your answer on MathOverflow this was restricted to Hermitian matrices. What has happened to that hypothesis (which certainly wasn't there without reason)?

Comment: Marc, the OP wondered if, in the case of hermitian matrices, there is a proof not using M.T.'s theorem.