# Maximal dimension and diagonalisable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> What is the maximmal dimension of a vector subspace of $\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R})$ formed by diagonalisable matrices $\mathcal{D}_n(\Bbb{R})$?

Attempt :

Let $\mathcal{S}_n(\Bbb{R})$ the set of symmetric matrices, wich is a subspace of $\mathcal{D}_n(\Bbb{R})$ of dimension $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and denote $\mathcal{T}_n(\Bbb{R})$ the set of upper triangular matrice with zero diagonal , wich is a subspace of $\mathcal{D}_n(\Bbb{R})$ of dimension $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Then $\mathcal{S}_n(\Bbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{M}_n(\Bbb{R})$ are in direct sum.

How can I continue ?

NB: I am also curious if we replace $\Bbb{R}$ by $\Bbb{C}$ ?

Comment: @RossMillikan Edited. Thanks

Comment: $\mathcal T_n$ consists of non-diagonalizable matrices, so it's certainly not a subspace of $\mathcal D_n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right. Only zero matrices lol. my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimension of a diagonalisable matrix subspace $V$ over *any* field is always bounded above by $n(n+1)/2$. This is because $V\cap\mathcal T_n=0$ and $V+\mathcal T_n\subseteq\mathcal M_n$, so that $\dim V\le\dim\mathcal M_n-\dim\mathcal T_n$.

So, for the real case, by considering the space of all symmetric matrices, we see that the maximal dimension is indeed $n(n+1)/2$. However, for complex matrices (or over any algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ with $p=0$ or $p\ge n$), by [Motzkin-Taussky theorem](http://books.google.com/books?id=7LQHEe157GQC&pg=PA304&lpg=PA304&dq=Motzkin-Taussky%20theorem&source=bl&ots=pYkrYYWkYC&sig=m2TQqgx6Pchg2Rip8VO96Snu8Oo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YRKzU9e3Eo748QXdmIDICA&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=Motzkin-Taussky%20theorem&f=false), those matrices in the diagonalisable subspace must commute. It follows that all matrices in the subspace are simultaneously diagonalisable and hence the maximal dimension is $n$.

**Related:** [All linear combinations diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$ implies commuting.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/820784)

Comment: Thanks but I do not see why using all symmetric matrices we have the result ?

Comment: @Yass Huh? The matrix subspace formed by all real symmetric matrices has dimension $n(n+1)/2$, doesn't it?

Comment: Sure. I just do not understand why because of this and your first claim then we can conclude that the maximal demension is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, now Ì have understand. Thanks. Just a curious question now, why community wiki ?

Comment: This is just a summary of some results in the literature, but not something that I've cooked up. Hence community wiki.